# Pushed node_modules but cant figure out how to remove

Tags: node-modules, gitignore

I push the node modules up to GitHub, then realized I did not have a `.gitignore`.

I added the `gitignore` but it did not fix the problem.
I found answers on here that said to remove it from the cached with `git rm -r --cached node_modules`, but this wont work because it says it cannot find that file, and I can still see it in my repo as well.

My file structure is the repo, then a `dev` folder with `node_modules` inside it, along with all the other code I have written.
The `.gitignore` is outside of the `dev` folder, next to the `README` file.

Do I need to give the `.gitignore` a path to find the modules like a `./node_modules` or something?

Answer (score 0):

> the gitignore is outside of the dev folder next to the readme file

Then, it should include:

```
dev/node_modules/
```

That would ignore the `dev/node_modules` folder, and its content.

Check that (after a `git rm --cached dev/node_modules` done from the root folder of your repo) with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- dev/node_modules/afile
```

(test it on one existing file inside that `dev/node_modules/` folder)

Answer (score 0):

If you've added just `node_modules` in the `.gitignore` file, then it ignores all the `node_modules` directories within the repo. So you are just fine with .gitignore configuration.

The issue is that you should use the correct path when removing the cached copy of the node_modules. It should be as follows from the root of your repository.

`git rm -r --cached ./dev/node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

Add this in .gitignore

```
dev/node_modules/
```

Now reset cache.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```